# Jacobian matrix of logits with respect to image using tf.GradientTape

Tags: tensorflow, gradient, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras, gradienttape

I am trying to find the Jacobian of logits with respect to input but I do get `None` and I could not figure it why.

Let'say I have a model, I trained it and saved it.

```
import tensorflow as tf
print("TensorFlow version: ", tf.__version__)
tf.keras.backend.set_floatx('float64')

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

#Normalize the images, between 0-1
x_train, x_test = x_train / 255.0, x_test / 255.0

# Add a channels dimension
x_train = x_train[..., tf.newaxis]
x_test = x_test[..., tf.newaxis]

print(x_train.shape)
#(60000, 28, 28, 1)

print(y_train.shape)
(60000,)

print(x_test.shape)
#(10000, 28, 28, 1)

print(y_test.shape)
#(10000,)

num_class = 10

# Convert labels to one hot encoded vectors.
y_train_oh, y_test_oh = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes= num_class, dtype='float32'), tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, num_classes= num_class, dtype='float32')

print(y_train_oh.shape)
#(60000, 10)
print(y_test_oh.shape)
#(10000, 10)

batch_size = 32
train_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_train, y_train_oh)).shuffle(10000).batch(batch_size)

test_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_test, y_test_oh)).batch(batch_size)


IMG_SIZE = (28, 28, 1)
input_img = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=IMG_SIZE)

hidden_layer_1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters = 16, kernel_size = (3, 3), strides=(1, 1), padding='same', activation=tf.nn.relu)(input_img)
hidden_layer_2 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters = 32, kernel_size = (3, 3), strides=(2, 2), padding='same', activation=tf.nn.relu)(hidden_layer_1)
hidden_layer_3 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters = 64, kernel_size = (3, 3), strides=(2, 2), padding='same', activation=tf.nn.relu)(hidden_layer_2)

flatten_layer = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(hidden_layer_3)
output_img = tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_class)(flatten_layer)
#NO SOFTMAX LAYER IN THE END, WE WILL DO IT LATER
#predictions = tf.nn.softmax(logits)

model = tf.keras.Model(input_img, output_img)

model.summary()

loss_object = tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
# This function accepts one-hot encoded labels

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()

train_loss = tf.keras.metrics.Mean(name='train_loss')
train_accuracy = tf.keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy(name='train_accuracy')

test_loss = tf.keras.metrics.Mean(name='test_loss')
test_accuracy = tf.keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy(name='test_accuracy')

@tf.function
def train_step(images, labels):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    # training=True is only needed if there are layers with different
    # behavior during training versus inference (e.g. Dropout).
        predictions = model(images, training=True)
        loss = loss_object(labels, predictions)
    gradients = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, model.trainable_variables))

    train_loss(loss)
    train_accuracy(labels, predictions)

@tf.function
def test_step(images, labels):
    # training=False is only needed if there are layers with different
    # behavior during training versus inference (e.g. Dropout).
    predictions = model(images, training=False)
    t_loss = loss_object(labels, predictions)

    test_loss(t_loss)
    test_accuracy(labels, predictions)

# Train the model for 15 epochs.
num_epochs = 15

train_loss_results = []
train_accuracy_results = []
test_loss_results = []
test_accuracy_results = []

for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    # Reset the metrics at the start of the next epoch
    train_loss.reset_states()
    train_accuracy.reset_states()
    test_loss.reset_states()
    test_accuracy.reset_states()

    for images, labels in train_ds:
        train_step(images, labels)

    for test_images, test_labels in test_ds:
        test_step(test_images, test_labels)

    train_loss_results.append(train_loss.result())
    train_accuracy_results.append(train_accuracy.result())
    test_loss_results.append(test_loss.result())
    test_accuracy_results.append(test_accuracy.result())

    template = 'Epoch {}, Loss: {}, Accuracy: {}, Test Loss: {}, Test Accuracy: {}'
    print(template.format(epoch+1,
                        train_loss.result(),
                        train_accuracy.result()*100,
                        test_loss.result(),
                        test_accuracy.result()*100))

tf.keras.models.save_model(model = model, filepath = 'model.h5', overwrite=True, include_optimizer=True)

# Epoch 1, Loss: 0.1654163608489558, Accuracy: 95.22, Test Loss: 0.061988271648914496, Test Accuracy: 97.88
# Epoch 2, Loss: 0.060983153790452826, Accuracy: 98.15833333333333, Test Loss: 0.044874734015780696, Test Accuracy: 98.53
# Epoch 3, Loss: 0.042541984771347297, Accuracy: 98.69, Test Loss: 0.042536806688480366, Test Accuracy: 98.57000000000001
# Epoch 4, Loss: 0.03330485398344463, Accuracy: 98.98166666666667, Test Loss: 0.039308084282613225, Test Accuracy: 98.64
# Epoch 5, Loss: 0.024959077225852524, Accuracy: 99.205, Test Loss: 0.04370295960736327, Test Accuracy: 98.67
# Epoch 6, Loss: 0.020565333928674955, Accuracy: 99.33666666666666, Test Loss: 0.04245114839809372, Test Accuracy: 98.69
# Epoch 7, Loss: 0.01639637468442185, Accuracy: 99.47666666666667, Test Loss: 0.04561551753656099, Test Accuracy: 98.72999999999999
# Epoch 8, Loss: 0.013642370500962534, Accuracy: 99.56333333333333, Test Loss: 0.04333075060614142, Test Accuracy: 98.83
# Epoch 9, Loss: 0.010697861799085589, Accuracy: 99.655, Test Loss: 0.05918524164135248, Test Accuracy: 98.48
# Epoch 10, Loss: 0.011164671695055153, Accuracy: 99.61666666666666, Test Loss: 0.05492968221334442, Test Accuracy: 98.64
# Epoch 11, Loss: 0.008642793950046499, Accuracy: 99.69833333333334, Test Loss: 0.05367191278261649, Test Accuracy: 98.74000000000001
# Epoch 12, Loss: 0.00788155746288626, Accuracy: 99.74499999999999, Test Loss: 0.06254112380584512, Test Accuracy: 98.68
# Epoch 13, Loss: 0.006521700676742724, Accuracy: 99.77000000000001, Test Loss: 0.06381602274510409, Test Accuracy: 98.7
# Epoch 14, Loss: 0.007104389384812846, Accuracy: 99.75166666666667, Test Loss: 0.05241271737958395, Test Accuracy: 98.87
# Epoch 15, Loss: 0.006479600550850722, Accuracy: 99.77833333333334, Test Loss: 0.06816933916442823, Test Accuracy: 98.74000000000001
```

[image]

You can find the saved model in `h5` format in this [link](http://mmuratarat.github.io/model.h5), if you do not want to train it.

It works well so far, I can do predictions on some samples:

```
predictions = model(mnist_twos, training=False)

for i, logits in enumerate(predictions):
    class_idx = tf.argmax(logits).numpy()
    p = tf.nn.softmax(logits)[class_idx] #probabilities
    print("Example {} prediction: {} ({:4.1f}%)".format(i, class_idx, 100*p))

Example 0 prediction: 2 (100.0%)
Example 1 prediction: 2 (100.0%)
Example 2 prediction: 2 (100.0%)
Example 3 prediction: 2 (100.0%)
Example 4 prediction: 2 (100.0%)
Example 5 prediction: 2 (100.0%)
Example 6 prediction: 2 (100.0%)
Example 7 prediction: 2 (100.0%)
Example 8 prediction: 2 (100.0%)
Example 9 prediction: 2 (100.0%)
```

What I want to do is now to find the jacobian matrix of logits with respect to input image. Since I have 10 selected images, I will have a Jacobian matrix of size `(10, 28, 28, 1)` since the shape of the MNIST sample is `(28, 28, 1)`. I can do this with Tensorflow 1.0 like:

```
for i in range(n_class):
    if i==0:
        j = tf.gradients(tf.reshape(logits, (-1,))[i], X_p)
    else:
        j = tf.concat([j, tf.gradients(tf.reshape(logits, (-1,))[i], X_p)],axis=0)
```

where `X_p` is the placeholder for the image I am feeding in.

```
X_p = tf.placeholder(shape=[28, 28, 1], dtype=tf.float32)
```

However, I am currently using Tensorflow 2.0 and I cannot make it work using `tf.GradientTape`. It always ends up `None`. This seems to be a common problem for everyone and I followed the examples [here](http://blog.ai.ovgu.de/posts/jens/2019/001_tf20_pitfalls/index.html) but to no avail. Can someone help me about it?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the batch_jacobian method of the GradinetTape. https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/GradientTape#batch_jacobian

Convert your input to the tf variable if you are getting None gradients even after batch_jacobian.